# How to merge two rows when one row has a greater value than the next one

Tags: r

I hope that you are having a good day. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Day.Number  Steps   Sleep   Moderate    Vigorous
1           3800    6622    5631        32
2           7372    33346   8499        0
3           10259   10914   11750       73
1           1798    8298    2667        0
2           5193    14859   6795        0
```

I am trying to find a way to do the following: if the value in a row in the Day.Number column is less than the value in the previous row in that same column, sum all the values across these two rows. Additionally, I want that the Day.Number for this new row created be the same as the highest Day.Number of the two rows that were merged. I hope that this makes sense. The output I am looking for looks like the following:

```
Day.Number  Steps   Sleep   Moderate    Vigorous
1           3800    6622    5631        32
2           7372    33346   8499        0
**3         12057   19212   14417       73**
2           5193    14859   6795        0
```

Note that the rows with Day.Number equal to 3 and 1 were merged and the values of Step, Sleep, Moderate, Vigorous of those two rows were added.
I will highly appreciate your help!

Comment: No pictures of data. Use text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(c(0, diff(Day.Number)) >= 0)) %>%
  summarise(Day.Number = max(Day.Number), 
            across(Steps:Vigorous, sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-group)

#  Day.Number Steps Sleep Moderate Vigorous
#       <int> <int> <int>    <int>    <int>
#1          1  3800  6622     5631       32
#2          2  7372 33346     8499        0
#3          3 12057 19212    14417       73
#4          2  5193 14859     6795        0
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(Day.Number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), Steps = c(3800L, 
7372L, 10259L, 1798L, 5193L), Sleep = c(6622L, 33346L, 10914L, 
8298L, 14859L), Moderate = c(5631L, 8499L, 11750L, 2667L, 6795L
), Vigorous = c(32L, 0L, 73L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: !!! Thank you so so very much!!! I am new in R and have been trying to do this for two days and could not do it. You are my hero! I highly appreciate your help. I am new here. For sure, I will learn how to provide data in reproducible format. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `by` which basically combines `split` and `lapply`. We split by the lagged cumulated sum of days (where we need to remove the last element `-(nrow(DF) + 1)`. In the splits, `if` `nrow > 1` we use `colSums` of the last 2 rows and remove the last row. Finally we `rbind` the list using `do.call`.

```
DF <- do.call(rbind, 
        by(DF, c(FALSE, cumsum(c(0, diff(DF$Day.Number)) < 0))[-(nrow(DF) + 1)], \(x) {
          if ((n <- nrow(x)) > 1) {
            x[n - 1, -1] <- colSums(x[n:(n - 1), -1])
            x[-n, ]
          } else {
            x
          }
        }))
DF
#     Day.Number Steps Sleep Moderate Vigorous
# 0.1          1  3800  6622     5631       32
# 0.2          2  7372 33346     8499        0
# 0.3          3 12057 19212    14417       73
# 1.5          2  5193 14859     6795        0
# 1.6          3 12057 19212    14417       73
# 2            2  5193 14859     6795        0
```

### Benchmark

According to the benchmark, `by` is considerably faster.

```
# Unit: milliseconds
# expr        min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#    by  1.439487  1.484082  1.603933  1.594348  1.662519  1.976049   100  a 
# dplyr 13.490445 13.785569 14.804602 14.155816 15.136579 25.462368   100   b
```

---

*Data:*

Your (slightly extended) toy data set.

```
DF <- read.table(header=T, text='
                Day.Number  Steps   Sleep   Moderate    Vigorous
1           3800    6622    5631        32
2           7372    33346   8499        0
3           10259   10914   11750       73
1           1798    8298    2667        0
2           5193    14859   6795        0
3           10259   10914   11750       73
1           1798    8298    2667        0
2           5193    14859   6795        0
                
                ')
```